# Nautilus acting weird in 23.10

Tags: nautilus, 23.04, 23.10

In Nautilus, whenever I scroll up or down to view all the files, it skips and jumps all over the place making it almost impossible to find files. This started with 23.04 and I was hoping the devs would fix it with 23.10, but it's still there. Is there any way to fix this or is just a bug that devs need to work out?

Comment: The file explorer is called Nautilus.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that scrolling with the touchpad using two finger gesture. I also cannot reproduce that when using the scrolbar.

Comment: It seems to do it when there's a lot of files in a folder. I have a lot of music files on my laptop. It didn't do it with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This has been a known issue for quite some time, I think it started earlier than 23.04.

Comment: Ah, ok. I just noticed it in 23.04.

Comment: So I just installed Thunar instead. This Nautilus bug is impossible to work with. I would uninstall Nautilus to free up space (I'm not sure how much would be freed up), but I don't want to break the OS (I did something like that similar in Windows years ago, lol).